# Do the ECLSS components aboard ISS deteriorate at the same rate as they would on Earth?

Tags: iss, eclss

Just what the title states.

Wikipedia writes to say about the [ECLSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISS_ECLSS) (Environment Control Life Support System)

> The highest priority for the ECLSS is the ISS atmosphere, but the system also collects, processes, and stores waste and water produced and used by the crew—a process that recycles fluid from the sink, shower, toilet, and condensation from the air

Atmosphere is controlled by the following components

- [Air Revitalisation System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISS_ECLSS#Air_revitalisation_system)
- [Oxygen Generation System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISS_ECLSS#Oxygen_generating_system)
- [Elektron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISS_ECLSS#Elektron)
- [Vika](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISS_ECLSS#Vika)
- [Vozdukh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISS_ECLSS#Vozdukh)
- Do the various components of the ECLSS suffer failure at the same rate aboard ISS as they would here on Earth?
- Was a comparative evaluation ever performed against a control unit on Terra Firma?